# Android Studio build error: Can't load a class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I didn't even do anything to the app and it gave the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/kotlin/annotation/plugin/ide/AnnotationBasedPluginModelBuilderService
```

I configured this project with Java and API 21, and is on Windows OS

What I've tried:

- Deleting .gradle
- Deleting the entire project
- Changing the jre used for build to the jdk I installed on my computer, which is JDK14

Aand it doesn't work. Any help appreciated!

EDIT : One more thing attempted: disabled then enabled the Kotlin plugin, still does not work. Thanks user @Android_id for suggesting the possibility though!

Comment: Where do I find the kotlin plugin? Also, I've configured this project with java

Comment: Now it's telling me this: Problems found loading plugins:
    Plugin "Android Support" was not loaded: required plugin "Kotlin" is disabled.

Comment: It was originally enabled, I disabled and restarted - above error - enabled and restarted - same error as original

Comment: If it matters, I haven't installed anything Kotlin related (I was told I don't need to). Could that be why, and should I try downloading Kotlin?

Comment: Yeah, what I'm saying is I haven't downloaded anything about the Kotlin language (sorry I don't know anything about Kotlin, don't know if I need to download something like a jdk for that too). But yeah, looks like it ain't the plugin :(((

Comment: Yes . Will help you find solution .have upvoted your question so that someone can help

Comment: Have you tried to downgrade to JDK8?

Comment: Yes; in fact, I tried JDK8 before JDK14